# Get or create in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

How can I make a `get_or_create` function in Meteor (something like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)?

Do I have to use

```
var element = Elements.findOne({number: 32});
if (element) {
  var elementId = element._id;
} else {
  // override element
  element = Elements.insert({number: 32});
  var elementId = element._id;
}

// do something with elementId
```

It seems not so handy.

I wondered if Meteor or MongoDB has something already built-in just like `Collection.upsert()`.

Comment: Maybe this is exactly what `upsert: true` does, except that it doesn't return the document?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout MongoDB [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). Below is an example to achieve what you are describing.

```
collection.findAndModify({
  query: { _id: "someId" },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: { foo: "bar" }
  },
  new: true,   // return new doc if one is upserted
  upsert: true // insert document if it does not exist
})
```

Comment: I was about to comment on the question that this is the best method. But Meteor does not support it currently. There is [`.findAndModify`](https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify) as a package that can alter behaviour though.

Comment: What is the reason for Meteor not to support it?